jcanvas zoomed and dragging handles
There is a zoomed jcanvas and there is a rectangle layer on image above it. If I drag or move the rectangle layer with mouse the position of layer quicker / slower than mouse depending on the zoom value.
I tried to solve the problem with updateDragX and updateDragY but the rectangle jumped over when the value of zoom was larger than 1.
smpl.canvas.addLayer( {
      type: "rectangle",
      name: "Rectangle",
      strokeStyle: stroke,
      strokeWidth: strokew,
      strokeDash:[ 5, 5 ],
      x: p.x,
      y: p.y,
      width:  p.width - 5,
      height: p.height - 5,
      draggable: true,
      drag: function(e){
        // some code here
      },
      handlemove: function(e){   
        // some code here
      },
      resizeFromCenter: false,
      constrainProportions: false,
      handlePlacement: 'both',
      handle:{
      type: "arc",
        fillStyle: smpl.fillStyle,
        strokeStyle: stroke,
        strokeWidth: strokew,
        radius: radius,  
      },
      updateDragX: function( layer, x ) {
          return Math.round( x / zoom);             
      },
      updateDragY: function ( layer, y ) {
          return Math.round( y / zoom);
      }
    }).drawLayers();`

